# How can I get to_json to escape front slashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, if I call `"</script>".to_json`, the result is `"\"</script>\""`. Neither angle brackets or front slashes are escaped. Is there a way to get to_json to escape these?

This little erb snippet demonstrates the problem:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
var a = <%= raw("</script>".to_json) %>;
alert("hi");
<% end %>
```

This produces the following output:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[

    var a = "</script>";
    alert("hi");

//]]>
</script>
```

In this case, the script tag is closed prematurely. Anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Can you show the response or code that you are trying to do this for?

Comment: Actually, with an X(HT)ML parser, it's not; the CDATA section is ended by `]]>`. As a sidenote, since I dislike merely "escaping" things, and you can't write a JavaScript string literal that works inside both `''` and `""`, I eventually decided on using `String.fromCharCode()`. Ew....

Comment: Do you want something like `&lt;/script&gt;`?

Answer (score 6):

The slashes can be removed by using JSON.parse().

First of all you need to extract the body from the response that you are getting.

```
response_body = response_you_get_after_request.body
```

then pass response as argument as following:-

```
 filtered_response = JSON.parse(response_body).
```

Comment: I was just having a problem like this and your solution was a big help- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= raw escape_javascript("</script>".to_json) %>
```

produces...

```
\"<\/script>\"
```

Is this what you're looking for?